# Spawn de notas midi python

Tags: python, game, blender

eu quero criar um jogo estilo guitar hero eu fiz um prototipo no blender
usei como base um curso de infinity runner no blender, eu gostaria de criar um spawn de notas que estao contidas em um arquivo.midi ou arquivo.chart, no curso ele ensina a fazer um spawn aleatorio mas isso nao me serve, eu andei procurando mas nao achei um jeito de fazer isso, alguma ideia para eu dar o primeiro passo?

Answer (score 1):

é só ler as notas a partir de um arquivo midi - 
Para fazer isso sem ter que você mesmo implementar toda a leitura de um arqivo midi para extrair as notas, precisa ter uma biblioteca midi pra isso - 
O primeiro hit no google parece bom:

https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi

Instale ela num [virtualenv](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/understanding-virtual-environments-in-python--cms-28272) do Python e experimente - se conseguir ler o arquivo midi e ter valores pras notas que você saiba interpretar, basta copiar a pasta "midi" da biblioteca que, depois de instalada vai estar na pasta ..../site-packages/midi do seu virtualenv para a pasta de `modules` do Blender - (no Linux fica em `~/.config/blender/<versao>/Scripts/modules`  - ao lado da pasta `addons`, e ela poderá ser usada normalmente por seus scripts rodando dentro do Blender.

Mais que isso é impossível ajudar, já que você não colocou *nenhum* exemplo do seu código, ou do que está tentando fazer.